# How to solve "Undefined variable $fields error !" issue?

Tags: backend, laravel-8, web-development-server

As I am currently working on a home service project and also new in Laravel, I am facing an undefined variable error. I have created a `AdminAddServiceCategoryComponent.php` in `App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminAddServiceCategoryComponent` folder and `admin-add-service-category-component.blade.php` in `resources\views\livewire\admin\admin-add-service-category-component.blade.php` folder.

**AdminAddServiceCategoryComponent.php:**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;
    
    use App\Models\ServiceCategory;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
    
    class AdminAddServiceCategoryComponent extends Component
    {
        use WithFileUploads;
        public $name;
        public $slug;
        public $image;
    
        public function generateSlug()
        {
            $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name,'-');
        }
        public function updated($fields)
        {
            $this->validateOnly($fields,[
                  'name' => 'required',
                  'slug' => 'required',
                  'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png'
            ]);
        }
        public function createNewCategory()
        {
            $this->validate($fields,[
                'name' => 'required',
                'slug' => 'required',
                'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png'
          ]);
          $scategory = new ServiceCategory();
          $scategory->name= $this->name;
          $scategory->slug= $this->slug;
          $imageName=Crabon::now()->timestamp. '.' . $this->image->extension();
          $this->image->storeAs('categories',$imageName);
          $scategory->image=$imageName;
          $imageName->save();
          session()->flash('message','Category has been created successfully!');
        }
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-service-category-component')->layout('layouts.base');
        }
    }
```

**admin-add-service-category-component.blade.php:**

```
    <div>
        <div class="section-title-01 honmob">
            <div class="bg_parallax image_02_parallax"></div>
            <div class="opacy_bg_02">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Add Service Category</h1>
                    <div class="crumbs">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li>/</li>
                            <li>Add Service Category</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="content-central">
            <div class="content_info">
                <div class="paddings-mini">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row portfolioContainer">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 profile1">
                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                   <div class="panel-heading">
                                       <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                 Add New Service Category
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <a href="{{route('admin.service_categories')}}" class="btn btn-info pull-right">All categories</a>
                                            </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="panel-body">
                                       @if(Session::has('message'))
                                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                                       @endif
                                       <form class="form-horizontal" wire:submit.prevent="createNewCategory">
                                           @csrf
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label for="name" class="col-label col-sm-3">Category Name:</label>
                                             <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" wire:model="name" wire:keyup="generateSlug">
                                                  @error('name') <p class="text-danger">{{$message}}</p> @enderror
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label for="slug" class="col-label col-sm-3">Category Slug:</label>
                                             <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="slug" wire:model="slug">
                                                  @error('slug') <p class="text-danger">{{$message}}</p> @enderror
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <label for="image" class="col-label col-sm-3">Category Image:</label>
                                             <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image" wire:model="image">
                                                  @error('image') <p class="text-danger">{{$message}}</p> @enderror
                                                  @if($image)
                                                     <img src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}" width="60">
                                                  @endif
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add Category</button>
                                       </form>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>   
            </div>      
        </section>    
    </div>
```

After submitting the form below :
[Form_submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQvCs.png)

These errors are being showed:
[error_screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwUIk.png)

[error_screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33DBH.png)

How can I resolve this issue ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined these items in $fillable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added $fields in createNewCategory()
try like this

```
 public function createNewCategory($fields)
    {
        $this->validate($fields,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png'
      ]);
      $scategory = new ServiceCategory();
......
```